# SUM based on two columns for Project and ID

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Currently, I am looking to find the 30 day SUM() for individual IDs, per Project type (aka, groupby) that is based on the Start Date for the ID and Project. This should be repeated at every instance the same ID and Project codes appear. I know the query to help me get monthly SUM by ID and project, but monthly sums does not answer my question.

Here is a sample dataset:

```
ID  Project Amount  Start Date
1234    203 29.65   5/29/18
1234    203 2       6/24/18
1234    203 345.34  7/12/18
1234    201 100     7/16/18
1234    203 200     7/16/18
2345    251 3       4/11/17
2345    251 4       4/16/17
2345    203 95.12   8/13/18
2345    203 10      4/12/19
3456    251 50      3/23/18
3456    251 100     3/23/18
3456    251 43.75   6/5/18
```

In the past, I have tried a basic query that gives me a groupby ID and Project, and monthly SUM() on Amount. Conducting monthly sums however does not answer my question. I would like the 30 day time frame to start when the ID and Project are first seen.

Here is the sample code I am using for monthly sums.

```
df.groupby(['ID', 'Project', pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='M')])['Amount'].sum()
```

```
ID  Project Amount  Start Date  New Sum
1234    203 29.65   5/29/18     Blank
1234    203 2       6/24/18     31.65
1234    203 345.34  7/12/18     Blank
1234    201 100     7/16/18     100
1234    203 200     7/16/18     545.34
2345    251 3       4/11/17     Blank
2345    251 4       4/16/17     7
2345    203 95.12   8/13/18     95.12
2345    203 10      4/12/19     10
3456    251 50      3/23/18     Blank
3456    251 100     3/23/18     150
3456    251 43.75   6/5/18      43.75
```

Comment: instead of having it blank, can you do a running tally and just have that column be equal to the value of the current amount?

Comment: @AnnaNevison That is a great suggestion. Unfortunately, it would be difficult for me to then find the average for a specific ID and Project. If the tally appears as Blank, I know that it has already been added to another item, and so it becomes easy for me to filter the data.

Comment: would you be open to creating a fifth column that is true or false for you to be able to sort if it's the one you want an average over? the blanks would be difficult to sort by because they are going to be none type vs. integer rather than comparing boolean true/false

Comment: Actually though, if a running sum was done or the column was equal to the current amount, then if another column could be added with some sort of a flag I can filter on, that would work too.

Comment: You are reading my mind @AnnaNevison! If a fifth column is created, which lets me know that this is the final SUM for the 30 days, then yes that would be great.

Comment: @AnnaNevison I updated my post to show a bug I am not able to figure out the answer to after a thorough QA process. I would appreciate your help, please! The Period is resetting itself. Not sure if there is a way to take into account the ID and Project to maybe solve this?

Comment: I would create a new question with the code your running and the issue! This one is marked as answered and it's old so a new question would be better so that it's at the top queue and others will see it if I can't figure it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideal solution would be to use:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('something.csv')

df['Start Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Date'], infer_datetime_format=True)
df = df.sort_values(by='Start Date')
new_df1 = (df.groupby(['ID', 'Project', pd.Grouper(key='Start Date', freq='M')]).agg({'Amount':'sum'}))
print(new_df1)
```

Which gives you:

```
ID   Project Start Date        
1234 201     2018-07-31  100.00
     203     2017-04-30  200.00
             2018-05-31   29.65
             2018-06-30   52.00
             2018-07-31  645.34
2345 203     2018-08-31   95.12
             2019-04-30   10.00
     251     2017-04-30    7.00
3456 251     2018-03-31  150.00
             2018-06-30   43.75
```

However, this is a little off from yours because the '5/29/18' value you want to add into 6/12/18 and 6/24/18 are not actually within the same month- so it's considering as a standalone value.

If you want to customize the frequency based on the dates you have in your 'Start Date' column, a solution is to sort based on date, use the first date as a start and add 30 to it, find all values in that range and assign them some unique 'Period' id (i set it as the index for the start value), then find the first value that goes outside of the range and reassign that as start and repeat the process. Here's a working code of that, which produces your desired output:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('something.csv')

df['Start Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Date'], infer_datetime_format=True)
df = df.sort_values(by='Start Date')

df['Period'] = np.nan
indices = df.index.values.tolist()
start = indices[0]
for v in range(0, len(indices)):
    if v == 0:
        df['Period'] = start
    else:
        if df['Start Date'].loc[indices[v]] - df['Start Date'].loc[start] < pd.Timedelta(days=30):
            df['Period'].loc[indices[v]] = start
        else:
            df['Period'].loc[indices[v]] = indices[v] 
            start = indices[v]
new_df = (df.groupby(['ID', 'Project', 'Period']).agg({'Amount':'sum'}))
print(new_df)
```

output:

```
ID   Project Period        
1234 201     6       100.00
     203     3        81.65
             6       645.34
             11      200.00
2345 203     9        95.12
             10       10.00
     251     11        7.00
3456 251     3        43.75
             13      150.00
```

Comment: @Logan the only difference between my answer and your expected in mine the 31.65 and 545.34 are added to get 576.99, but I double checked and those values have the same ID, and project and fall within the same date range so is it possible you have a calculation error on yours with that? If not, let me know how you calculated those so I can adjust my code !

Comment: I was just looking into that as well. Sorry if it will take me a few to run the code. I simply want to be sure I do not waste more of your time! I truly do appreciate the time you have taken thus far to help me. I know you have your own work to do, and so I really do value your time! I will review and get back to you soon.

Comment: I think this is where it gets complicated. So, I am still expecting two Amount Totals of 31.65 and 545.34, labeled as False. Even though the ID and Project are the same, the 30 day window should be for two different points.

For example, the start date of 5/29/18 should end 30 days after on 6/28/18. So, the $345.34 on 7/12/18 and 200 on 7/16/18 should not be added to the previous 30 day window. A new 30 day window sum should be created. Do I make sense?

Comment: One final question though Anna if I may, should I be concerned of the following warning message:

"/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:190: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)"

Comment: Also, @Anna, thank you so much!! This is exactly what I expect the outcome to look like. I am more than impressed and so very thankful. To anyone reading this, if you have over 15 reputation points, can you please upvote Anna's answer? Unfortunately, I have less than 15 so it does not show.

Comment: @Logan the error message is not a big deal, it does not effect the output in anyway, it's just that this is not the best way to do it-but I wasn't sure of another. Also, no worries on the upvote, just make sure you mark the question as answered so it's not unanswered in the queue! Happy to help!

Comment: Thank you again, Anna. People like you and all the others who contribute continue to make this a better place! :)

Comment: @Logan yea I noticed that too immediately after I posted the revision, so I switched it back to .loc instead of .iat  (in the code above) because even though it gets rid of the warning, it's not working the way you need it to. The warning shouldn't cause you much issue, but if does let me know

Comment: Thanks, all problems solved and question marked as answered! You definitely spent some time on this - hats off to you!

Comment: How should I go about asking a follow up? I updated the sample dataset with a few more rows and I noticed some minor issues. Should I simply post another question, or edit my original post with the new sample dataset with the expected outcome?

Comment: @Logan can you add the new sample set to the original question as well as the current code you are running and then describe the issue?

Comment: Updated initial question with updated sample set, with expected and actual outputs that are occurring. Made a note that i am using the same code solution as provided above. Somehow, the 30 day window is shortening, but I can't seem to figure out how.

Comment: @Logan so you're adding these three to get 645.34?  1234    203 100     7/1/18      Blank
1234    203 345.34  7/12/18     Blank
1234    203 200     7/16/18     645.34

Comment: @Logan also, there was a tiny error in my code i flipped min and max so i updated and it produces your desired output for the most part.. but I only have it coded to do pairwise not in threes

Comment: Hey Anna, I hope I'm not too repetitive when I'm expressing my thanks, but I appreciate the continued help. You are correct in the ones I'm getting to equal 645.34. 

I have a larger dataset that does include set of pairs, threes, fours, etc. Would it be difficult to develop a code that takes into account nth number of start dates between the 30 day time period or have I finally run out of luck?

Comment: @Logan i got you, check the newest answer!

Comment: this works like a charm! I am also able to easily manipulate the timeframe as well which I was going to need to do - you killed two birds with one stone. Also, the query is extremely easy to read. Thanks for all of your time. I'll be running more QA checks, but so far it meets all my criteria!

Comment: Hey Anna, hope all is going well. I'm running into a bug, but not sure how to fix the code. This may be a long shot for you to reply back, but I did update my dataset to show the problem! 

Any help truly is appreciated. I continue to value your time! I did try to solve it, but with no luck. Hopefully no more bugs after this!

The problem seems to occur with the "Period" resetting even though the dates are all in ascending order.